# In R, how can I exclude specific lags in an autoregressive model?

Tags: r

For a bivariate case, I am using the grangertest(), which uses the lm() and waldtest() functions to compute a p value for comparing two models, the full and the restricted, for a specified lag number (the model order).

My question is: without using the this particular function, possibly using VAR() or another one, how can I exclude certain lags.  So, for example, if I want to compute a p-value for model order 5, using lags 4-9, instead of 1-5?  Thanks so much in advance, Ive been working on this for over a year!!
PS: for example it can be done in stata( scroll down to page 5): https://www.stata.com/manuals13/tsvar.pdf